# Separate unique and duplicate entries in dataframe based off id

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a dataframe with an id variable, which may be duplicated. I want to split this into two dataframes, one which contains only the entries where the id's are duplicated, the other which shows only the id's which are unique. What is the best way of doing this?

For example, say I had the data frame:

```
dataDF <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6),
                      a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                      b = c(8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1))
```

i.e. the following

```
  id a b
1  1 1 8
2  1 2 7
3  2 3 6
4  3 4 5
5  4 5 4
6  4 6 3
7  5 7 2
8  6 8 1
```

I want to get the following dataframes:

```
  id a b
1  1 1 8
2  1 2 7
5  4 5 4
6  4 6 3
```

and

```
  id a b
3  2 3 6
4  3 4 5
7  5 7 2
8  6 8 1
```

I am currently doing this as follows

```
dupeIds  <- unique(subset(dataDF, duplicated(dataDF$id))$id)
uniqueDF <- subset(dataDF, !id %in% dupeIds)
dupeDF   <- subset(dataDF, id %in% dupeIds)
```

which seems to work but it seems a bit off to subset three times, is there a simpler way of doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `duplicated` twice, once top down, and once bottom up, and then use `split` to get it all in a `list`, like this:

```
split(dataDF, duplicated(dataDF$id) | duplicated(dataDF$id, fromLast = TRUE))
# $`FALSE`
#   id a b
# 3  2 3 6
# 4  3 4 5
# 7  5 7 2
# 8  6 8 1
# 
# $`TRUE`
#   id a b
# 1  1 1 8
# 2  1 2 7
# 5  4 5 4
# 6  4 6 3
```

If you need to split this out into separate `data.frame`s in your workspace (not sure *why* you would need to do that), assign `names` to the list items (eg `names(mylist) <- c("nodupe", "dupe")`) and then use `list2env`.